# Xamarin Android WindowSoftInput Resize (specific page)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Is there a way to implement the `Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustResize` to a specific page/control (e.g. a grid) rather than inserting it into `App.xaml.cs` or `MainActivity.cs` ?Since it is affecting my other pages when the keyboard is being shown.

Thanks!

Comment: try <ContentPage...
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
  ...
</ContentPage>

Comment: @GaurangDave This doesn't work, sorry about that. The `android xmlns` wouldn't be able to find `WindowSoftInputMode` since it is an `enum` and not a `class`

Comment: I checked this one : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/platform-specifics/consuming/android/#Setting_the_Soft_Keyboard_Input_Mode

Comment: @GaurangDave I think this won't work if it will be implemented to a specific page, since the application for it was implemented on `App.xaml` or its `cs`

Comment: As per this source, it is no longer available. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/90614/softinput-adjustresize-no-longer-working

Comment: @GaurangDave I have fixed it. I tried implementing the `cs` on `OnAppearing` and `OnDisappearing`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have solved my problem. What I did was to implement in on my `page.xaml.cs` on

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
}
```

This would resize your window when the keyboard is being shown when the page appears, and if you want to retain the normal behaviour of your `Entry` or other elements that will show your keyboard use this code:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);
}
```

The `WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan` is the default behaviour of Android when a keyboard is being shown. This way when your page disappears, the settings will go back to default.

Comment: The solution solves the specified issue. However: When calling     `App.Current.On<Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Pan);`
in a ModalPop ContentPage with a confirmation on closing ("Do you want to close?"), the window doesn't pop/close anymore. When removing this line of code, everything works find again, except for the issue of the Keyboard of course

Comment: My workaround is now to reset the InputMode, in the OnAppearing event of the Menu-Page in my MasterDetailPage (which is called, after the ModalPop ContentPage is closed. In this case, it does not affect the closing behavior any longer

Answer (score 0):

As supplement to @jbtamares' solution, I created an extension method which allows to easily revert to the original resize mode once the affected page disappears.

The extension method tracks the original resize modes once UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust is called on the page. ResetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust reads the original resize mode and sets it accordingly.

**This is the code of the extension method:**

```cs
public static class PageExtensions
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<Type, WindowSoftInputModeAdjust> OriginalWindowSoftInputModeAdjusts = new Dictionary<Type, WindowSoftInputModeAdjust>();
    
    public static void UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this Page page, WindowSoftInputModeAdjust windowSoftInputModeAdjust)
    {
        var platformElementConfiguration = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Android>();
        
        var pageType = page.GetType();
        if (!OriginalWindowSoftInputModeAdjusts.ContainsKey(pageType))
        {
            var originalWindowSoftInputModeAdjust = platformElementConfiguration.GetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust();
            OriginalWindowSoftInputModeAdjusts.Add(pageType, originalWindowSoftInputModeAdjust);
        }
        
        platformElementConfiguration.UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(windowSoftInputModeAdjust);
    }
    
    public static void ResetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(this Page page)
    {
        var pageType = page.GetType();
        
        if (OriginalWindowSoftInputModeAdjusts.TryGetValue(pageType, out var originalWindowSoftInputModeAdjust))
        {
            OriginalWindowSoftInputModeAdjusts.Remove(pageType);
            
            var platformElementConfiguration = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Android>();
            platformElementConfiguration.UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(originalWindowSoftInputModeAdjust);
        }
    }
}
```

**And here is how you apply it in the page:**

```cs
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        
        this.UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        
        this.ResetWindowSoftInputModeAdjust();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you find any problems with the code posted above.